# Filtering Data in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Hey I am trying to filter the following Input:

```
Id       Num
102369   100
623589   200
102369   300
103333   300
103333   100
...
```

Expected output relation should be reduced and only include all `ID` - `Num` relations for existing relations between `Id` and `Num == 300`:

```
Id     Num
102369 100
102369 300
103333 300
103333 100
```

I have tried it like this:

```
grouped = GROUP table BY Num;
filtered = FILTER grouped BY group == 300;
DUMP filtered;
```

But this does not work. Can you help me to solve this?

Kind regards.

Comment: If your expected output should include only records with num==300 why do you have two records 102369 100
102369 300 in your desired output?

Comment: Actually I want as output all `Id - Num` relations for the Id's which are related to `Num==300`.

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the Id of the record that has Num==300 and then use that as the filter.

Assuming all num==300 results in 1 unique value 102369

```
A = FILTER table BY (Num == 300);
B = LIMIT A 1; --This is to ensure you use only 1 value
C = FILTER table by B.$0;
DUMP C;
```

OR using JOIN if you have multiple ids for num==300

```
 A = FILTER table BY (Num == 300);
 B = JOIN table by Id,A BY A.$0;
 C = FOREACH B GENERATE B.$0,B.$1;
 DUMP C;
```

Comment: Good thing, sorry I have adapted my input data in the main post. Therefore this is not working anymore. Your solution only works for the first matched `ID` but in my case there are different `IDs` which match to `Num==300`.

Comment: @MathProgrammer In that case you have to use JOIN without using limit 1.Join will match all the ids.